# Почему будильник не срабатывает в чётко поставленное время в андроид?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я написал часть кода в своё приложение, которое играет роль будильника. Эта функция должна взять число в качестве времени  и проигрывать рингтон в это время. Я прогуглил и нашел видео про создание будильника и создал всё по туториалу. Ничего не получилось, будильник срабатывает только если открыть приложение. Посмотрите фрагмент кода может, вы знаете в чем проблема. Вот код будильника:

```html
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Ringtone ringtone;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        Uri notificationUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notificationUri);
        if (ringtone == null) {
            notificationUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notificationUri);
        }
        if (ringtone != null) {
            ringtone.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (ringtone != null && ringtone.isPlaying()) {
            ringtone.stop();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    }
```

```html
timeall=our_table.children().get(0).child(1).text();
                String[] split_time_split=timeall.split(":");
                int hour=Integer.parseInt(time_split[0]);
                int minute=Integer.parseInt(time_split[1]);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), getAlarmInfoPendingIntent());
                alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, getAlarmActionPendingIntent());
            }
        });
        
        
         private PendingIntent getAlarmInfoPendingIntent() {
        Intent alarmInfoIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        alarmInfoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alarmInfoIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private PendingIntent getAlarmActionPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

Comment: теперь гугли про работу приложения в фоновом режиме

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA